# Selected option value sending with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to insert into the database a selected option value and a text input with jQuery but I get a

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

```
<div class="text-field" id="catUp" >

            <form id="upload_category" method="post" >

            <div class="text-inside">
            <select id="select-category">
              <option value="audio">Audio,Video</option>
              <option value="electro">Electrocasnice</option>
              <option value="ingrijire">Ingrijire personala</option>
              <option value="pc">PC</option>
              <option value="telefoane">Tablete,telefoane</option>
            </select><br><br>
            <div id="insert-category">Nume Categorie<br>
            <input type="text" name="input-categorie" /><br><br>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" name="sumit" value="Adauga categorie" id="catButton" class="button"  /><br><br>
            </div>      


            </form>

    </div>
```

---

```
    $('#upload-category').on('submit', function(){
    var getCategory = '';
    var getCategoryName = $('#insert-category').val();

    $('#select-category').change(function(){
        var selectedCat = $('#select-category option:selected');
        getCategoryName = selectedCat;
    })

    var items = {
        'categorie': getCategory,
        'nume':getCategoryName
    }

    $.ajax({
        url:'category.php',
        type: 'post',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json'
        data:JSON.stringify(items)
    });

});
```

Comment: Why are you converting the parameters to JSON? PHP expects the parameters to be in url-encoded format, which is how `$.ajax` normally does it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
        url:'category.php',
        type: 'post',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',    //you forgot comma here
        data:JSON.stringify(items)
    });
```

you forgot comma here after this line  `dataType: 'json',`

Comment: can you accept this answer please if it helps you @alindradici Thanks.

Comment: @alindradici i'm waiting for your response Thnaks.

Answer (score 0):

Few things I have noticed.

```
//this is div
$('#insert-category').val(); 
//you probably wanted input value - add id to input-categorie and get value from there.
```

Why do you have change function inside submit? And you forgot **;** add the end of change function.

Add prevent default at the end of submit, to prevent from page reloading (return false;).

Comment: because I am trying to get the select box value, but it doesn't work

Comment: Just do it this way: var selectedCat = $('#select-category option:selected').val();.
No need of change function.